# CSS fixed+fluid in a single wrapper

Tags: html, css

How can I make the second div expand to the full width of the `footer` in [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/2/)?

I want to avoid giving a width to the second div. The first div has a fixed width of `80px`

**[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/4/)**: so how do I make the black fox have the same height as the light gray one?

Comment: For your Update: fake it by setting the background color of the container div to the same color as the fixed width div.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/4/

Comment: that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry, jsFiddle gave me the old link.  Here you go!  http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` and apply the float only to the first div.

[jFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/3/)

```
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

div:first-child {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: This behaves well as long as the first and second div's content has the same height.  http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/2/

Comment: That's true. Not designed for differing heights. If you need that, I suggest using percentage widths for both divs.

Comment: quick fix: set margin-left to width of the black box (padding included) + the actual margin. cool! [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dEDDa/5/)